# TypeError: 'person' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class EntryBook(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="b_entrybook")
    topiccenter = models.ForeignKey(TopicCenter, related_name="tc_books")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.book.title
```

and I am trying to save new object:

```
tc = TopicCenter.objects.get(id=int(tcid))
user = request.user.get_profile()
book = Book.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('bookid')))
newbookentry = EntryBook(status=1, person=user, book=book, topiccenter=tc)
newbookentry.save()
```

and I am getting the error message:

```
TypeError: 'person' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Given that `person` is the right attribute of the model, why would it be the invalid keyword argument?

Comment: Did you check values of user, book, tc? are they ok?

Comment: @akaRem, weird thing is, it is working in my local dev but on prod server it is giving this error. i think the user profile is somehow empty.. i have big problems with this get_profile() function all the time..

Answer (score 0):

```
newbookentry = EntryBook(status=1, person=user, book=book, topiccenter=tc)
```

should be:

```
newbookentry = EntryBook.objects.create(status=1, person=user, book=book,
    topiccenter=tc)
```

Comment: :D, wunderbar! let me test it

Comment: not working someone.. the thing is that it is working in my local dev but in production server i am getting this error..  in your answer, there is almost no difference between those two, right?

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like the call to `.get_profile()`might not be returning the object you expect, or an object at all. There's virtually no difference in the code, except that calling the `create()` model manager eliminates the manual call to `save()`

Comment: yes, this is also what i am thinking about now.. ``get_profile()`` is not returning anything i think..

Comment: You can always try it in the Django shell to test.

Comment: you are right, i was just thinking about how to test it .. :D